# How to sort a list of strings by a part of the string in prolog

Tags: sorting, prolog

If I have a list containing `123.1234,abc` and `321.321,qwe`, how can i sort the list by only the float value?

I have tried to use `sort/4`, but it doesn't work. Is it possible to use some other sort like keysort?

```
?- sort(["10.29127443524318,F","5.968607804131937,A"],LL).
LL = ["10.29127443524318,F", "5.968607804131937,A"].
```

when I do the above sort, it gives me wrong answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sorting is numeric for ints and floats, and alphabetic for strings (so in your example the sorting is correct, because "1" is alphabetically before "5").

You can convert string to numbers, but this results in an error if there are non-numeric parts in the string (such as `,F` in your example).

Therefore you need to split the string first, and sort the resulting lists of substrings. For a list of lists sorting is performed on the first element of the inner list, and then the second element if the first element is equal, etc.

After sorting the substrings can be concatenated again. Here the conversion from numbers back to strings can be performed implicitly during the concatenation.

Splitting, number conversion and recombination can be done in the basic Prolog recursive fashion.

MWE:

```
sort_compound(L1,LL) :-
    split_compound(L1,L2),
    sort(L2,L3),
    recombine(L3,LL).

split_compound([H|T],[[N,L2]|T2]) :-
    split_string(H,",","",[H1,L2]),
    number_string(N,H1),
    split_compound(T,T2).

split_compound([],[]).

recombine([[A,B]|T],[C|T2]) :-
    atomics_to_string([A,',',B],C),
    recombine(T,T2).

recombine([],[]).
```

Result:

```
?- sort_compound(["10.29127443524318,F","5.968607804131937,A"],LL).
LL = ["5.968607804131937,A", "10.29127443524318,F"].
```

Note that several SWI-Prolog specific predicates are used for data type conversion, so for other interpreters this needs to be adjusted.